# Single page template

Tags: customization, templates, page-template

I am trying to create a template for a custom page type that will put the same data on every page of this type. The only problem is I see examples of custom page types but only using loops. Do I have to use a loop if it is a single page. How will I fill in the data here like title and content.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Use Case Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">

    <div class="leftcol">

        <h3 class="usehd">
            TITLE
        </h3>

        <div class="hd-div">

        </div>
        <div class="use-content">
            CONTENT
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="rightcol">

        <div class="sideform">

            <form name="usecase" id="usecase">

                <label>Email</label><br>

                <input type="text" name="email" class="txtinput" />

                <br>

                <label>Full Name</label><br>

                <input type="text" name="fullname" class="txtinput" />

                <br>

                <label>Company Name</label><br>

                <input type="text" name="company" class="txtinput" />

                <br>

                <label>Number of employees</label><br>

                <select name="employeenum" class="useselect">

                    <option value="10">10</option>

                    <option value="100">100</option>

                    <option value="1000">1000</option>

                    <option value="9999">1000+</option>

                </select>

                <br>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="usecasesubmit" />

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, even for custom page templates, you will need to have a loop in order to get the title and content.

Try the following:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Use Case Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post; ?>
<div class="leftcol">

    <h3 class="usehd">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h3>

    <div class="hd-div">

    </div>
    <div class="use-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="rightcol">

    <div class="sideform">

        <form name="usecase" id="usecase">

            <label>Email</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="email" class="txtinput" />

            <br>

            <label>Full Name</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="fullname" class="txtinput" />

            <br>

            <label>Company Name</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="company" class="txtinput" />

            <br>

            <label>Number of employees</label><br>

            <select name="employeenum" class="useselect">

                <option value="10">10</option>

                <option value="100">100</option>

                <option value="1000">1000</option>

                <option value="9999">1000+</option>

            </select>

            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="usecasesubmit" />

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You could also end the foreach and if statements right after the end of the "leftcol" div.

Answer (score 0):

The reason while templates usually involve loop, is that even in sace of single post template - that is still technically a loop with single post.

You should really just study existing template, for example [that of Twenty Eleven](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/single.php), and apply same logic in yours.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save the custom content as a separate file.

**Example:**

Using your code:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="leftcol">
    <h3 class="usehd">TITLE</h3>
    <div class="hd-div"></div>
    <div class="use-content">CONTENT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">
    <div class="sideform">
      <form name="usecase" id="usecase">
        <label>Email</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="email" class="txtinput" />
          <br />
        <label>Full Name</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="fullname" class="txtinput" />
          <br />
        <label>Company Name</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="company" class="txtinput" />
          <br />
        <label>Number of employees</label><br />
        <select name="employeenum" class="useselect">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
          <option value="1000">1000</option>
          <option value="9999">1000+</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="usecasesubmit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could save that as form.php

Then in your custom template just use this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Use Case Template
*/
get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
  <?php the_content(); get_template_part('form') ?>
  <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>  
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Using the code get_template_part calls the form.php file into the template file. This way you could use a conditional statement to include the form if it is the custom post type. **You wouldn't need the custom template if you use the conditional statement to call the form.php from an existing template.**